# Will this circuit suffer from Shoot-Through? and is there a quick fix?

Tags: power, mosfet, cmos, gate-driving, shoot-through

I'm considering a high-side, low-side driver using the [DMG1016UDW](http://www.diodes.com/catalog/20v_complementary_142/dmg1016udw.html) COMPLEMENTARY PAIR ENHANCEMENT MODE MOSFET from diodes.

The [datasheet](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds31860.pdf) says The ON voltage is about 0.5V and ON the delays+rises is about 12ns, the off delays are around 27ns which might mean shoot-through is possible and could last about about 20ns (ignoring the rise time of the mcu signal).

The datasheet indicates solenoid driver as an application.  Is this not the right of driving it then? Or is shoot-through not an issue here?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEgqwE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

As a solenoid driver, the duty cycle is likely to be so low that while shoot-through will happen, the effects might not be serious enough to worry about,(especially given the 3V supply shown).

You would have to satisfy yourself that the power dissipaton in that 20ns, times the switching rate, is within acceptable limits; so that for instance it does not result in an unacceptable temperature rise in the FETs or exceed their max current ratings. For a solenoid the switching rate is unlikely to be more than a few Hz.

If it is, then adding complexity to the design to overcome shoot-through is unnecessary (though it may still be desirable, if it affects battery life for example, or puts unacceptable current spikes on the supply rail).

However, anyone taking this power stage and re-using it for a fast switching PWM circuit had better watch out!

Comment: So at really low frequencies (once every few minutes) the shoot through isn't going to kill the mosfets?  Would a current limiting diode place at VCC help?

Comment: You would have to satisfy yourself of that, doing the math with the on-resistances of the FETs and/or the current available from the supply, but yes, that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

Shoot through will be an issue unless you use a proper driver to segregate the timings of the gate drives. I would recommend you look at an LTC4444 but this is for driving two N channel FETs not an N and a P - these seem harder to find but I have a feeling Linear tech would source one.

If you are driving a solenoid you would probably only use one of the devices in the package and tie the other end of the solenoid to Vcc or ground, depending on using an N channel or P channel FET.

Comment: The idea is to be able to reverse the current through the solenoid using one MCU pin.

Answer (score 0):

One limitation with that design is that while you may not have shoot-through while the pin is high or while it is low, there is no apparent way to set the pin so that both transistors are off.  A nicer design if you can afford a 0.7-volt drop is to use an NPN emitter follower on the high side and a PNP emitter follower on the low side.  Otherwise, if you have multiple circuits to be controlled via multiple CPU pins, I would suggest that using external logic is often the way to go.