# Is this a proper small signal H-bridge?

Tags: h-bridge

The inductor in the middle is the coil of a single-coil latching relay, which requires a H-bridge to drive.

How do I add flyback to the `74HC04`'s internal MOSFETs? Or should I just rely on body diodes?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw7wE0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: See also: [What is the most economical way to drive an array of single coil latching relays?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/87649/25328)

Comment: You might consider [L2293Q Push-pull four channel driver with diodes](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00204113.pdf) which is small and could be used to drive two single-coil latching relays.

Comment: Forget the inductance (which isn't real anyways, it's just the default inductor, I know). What is the coil resistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute maximum ratings of the LVC family do not allow for 12V to be applied to an output (6.5V max), even of an OD device. You should either use a NMOSFET directly (since you seem to want to invert the input regardless) or use a 7406/7416 (since you want 3.3V interfacing) instead.

Comment: So all okay, just replace the `74LVC1G06` with `74HC06`?

Comment: No. HCMOS devices cannot handle that high a voltage at the output either. You need to use the TTL 7406.

Comment: Which means that the gates on the inside won't work either.

Comment: Then can I use a few discrete MOSFETs then? a lone `2N7002` replacing the `74LVC1G06` and a complimentary pair `AO4606` replacing the high-voltage `74HC04`?

Comment: Since the first MOSFET brings the voltage high enough to use the complementary pair, yes. But it won't be as efficient as an integrated H-bridge due to lack of dead time.

Comment: However what I need here is a small signal device here but all existing H-bridge chips are big - too big for me.

Comment: 7406 - Also no. 06s are open-collector devices and will not provide source current. Which you need. And forget the inductance - what is the coil resistance?

Answer (score 0):

Modern logic gates are not rated for 12Vdc ! The old HEFcmos series that would handle the volts has a very low gaurenteed Output current capability.Another hassle with old HEF is that inputs should be 12V so you would be up for some sort of level shifting .Why not use a mosfet driver like a mc4426 or similiar .They come in 8 pin package ,They are made by many manufacturers,They are generaly rated at 18V ,They accept 3v3 or 5v logic with thier mosfet inputs .You dont need pull up resistors or freewheeling diodes with these mosfet driver chips .It really is a full bridge .