# Drive Bistable Single Coil Relay with two MOSFETS

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, mosfet, relay

I am currently in the middle of the a project where I need to drive a relay.
Scavenging the parts I have around I have 2 STP55NF06L logic MOSFETs and a TE Connectivity PE014F12 Relay.

I wanted to drive this relay using an arduino, and while I have found some schematics online, none show how to drive this relay with 2 mosfets, as it is only a single coil relay.

Does anybody know a simple way to achieve this ? i have pleanty of passive components around, I just would rather avoid having to order a dual coil relay if possible.

Any help with a possible schematic for this would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: No, I'm not going to do your job and dig out the datasheets for you.

Comment: And also provide links to the schematics you found on-line.

Comment: [MOSFET](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/129279.pdf)
[relay](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1717951.pdf)

Im just wondering if its even possible, as everything i have seen online uses a H-Bridge or something similar. I don't mean to be asking you to do everything for me. I just want to know if im going in the right direction or if its even possible.

Comment: See also: [What is the most economical way to drive an array of single coil latching relays?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/87649/25328)

Comment: question: Why do you want to use two mosfets? does the polarity of the current going through the relay coil matter? Are there two normally open terminals instead of one normally open and one normally closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

When Q1's gate goes high, the R1 K1 node is pulled to ground, allowing charge to flow through R2 and K1's coil, latching the relay's contacts in one state.

After a time, when Q1's gate drive goes low, the relay will have been latched, and since there'll be be no potential difference across the relay's coil the contacts will be stable.

Then, when Q2's gate goes high, the R2 K1 node will be pulled to ground, through Q2, allowing charge to flow through R1 and K1's coil, latching the relay's contacts in the other bistable state.

After a time, when Q2's gate drive goes low, the relay will have been latched, and since there'll be be no potential difference across the relay's coil the contacts will be stable.

D1 and D2 are catch diodes which will shunt the relay's turnoff spikes to the 12 volt supply, clamping the spikes to about 13 volts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.
Hmm, I rigged that up on the breadboard, with 180 ohm resistors, what I found easiest in the pile of unorganised resistors.  Just bringing Q1 high and the other high alternately gives me a click from the relay every once and a while. Its odd and definitely isnt every time. Being honest I'm a software guy, and this is a bit alien to me. Any ideas why it seems so sporadic ?
If theres any other information i can provide let me know

Comment: Actually maybe its to do with the internal resistance of the coil being 650 ohm. Ill try use 1k resistors. (i have no idea what im doing :) )

Comment: @CathalODwyer: My pleasure, :)  Just as an aside, be aware that the 200 ohm values for R1 and R2 are based on a "must toggle" specification of 9 volts for the 12 volt relay. Lower resistances will decrease the transfer time delay, if that's important.

Comment: [Picture](http://i.imgur.com/iSvpyLc.jpg) that's what I have, the relay and mosfets are on a different board, sorry about the weird arrangement. The white and black wire coming from the other board is the relay coil. The orange, red, and brown cables are Source, Drain, Gate of FET 1 respectively and grey, purple, and blue are SDG of FET 2 respectively. Still cant get it to work consistently bringing Q1 or Q2 high. Any idea ? :/ Very sorry about the awkward picture, but its the same as your schematic.

Comment: @CathalODwyer: If you're getting missing hits, it sounds to me like you may be letting the gate of the OFF MOSFET float, which is a serious NO-NO. Once you've activated the relay, and it's latched, you need to ground the activating MOSFET's gate in order to seriously open-circuit its drain-to-source channel and let the pullups take over. As for the pullups, lowering their resistances will make them more effective.

Comment: I'm making sure to ground the gate of each MOSFET after I bring it high. Ill try lower resistances. It doesn't seem to be working at all now, and I tested the FETS and relay and they're working fine independently

Comment: OK, you're right, I'm wrong...

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude if that's how it cane across. Can you see anything done incorrectly in the picture I linked?

Comment: One of the MOSFETs was blown. Swapped it out and everything is working. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @CathalODwyer: Thanks for the accept, and oops... I forgot to include the mandatory catch diodes, which may have contributed to the demise of your MOSFET.  Sorry about that, and I'll edit my drawing right away.