# Latching relays connected in parallel not working as expected

Tags: capacitor, low-power, parallel, latching, latching-relay

I have a project I'm working on where I need 4 relays to open when power is applied to the board and close when power is lost. I need to use latching relays to conserve power as the device could be left powered for a long time. I have looked around for a solution and found the circuit [here](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/omronrelayprecautions.pdf) (starting on page 43) and discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65663/mystery-circuit-latching-relay-control-with-transitor-capacitor-why-doesnt).

I built and tested the circuit using one (1) [EC2-3SNU](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_R7002_EC2_EE2.pdf) single coil latching signal relay successfully. Even though my calculation per the document required around 187uF, it works perfectly with just 22uF. I also simulated this in Falstad simulator and it works, but with a bit different capacitor values.

The question I have is how can I modify this to work for 4 relays (or more for that matter) while keeping BOM count low? Thinking paralleling them is the best choice, I decided to do a test. Testing with 1 relay worked with 22uF. To get 2 relays working in parallel, I needed about 400uF. I then added the 3rd relay and added capacitors in parallel until I got about 1mF and it still didn’t work. At this point it’s too large a capacitor anyway to make sense moving forward. If I created the circuit (1 transistor, 2 diodes and cap) for every relay, it would significantly increase the BOM count.  Am I making a fatal mistake by assuming I can parallel the relays in this fashion? In my test circuit, I’m adding 100uF Tantalum capacitors in parallel to get higher level capacitances (for the test only). Is this an issue? Do I need a single capacitor for the test? I simulated 4 relays in Falstad simulator with a larger capacitor and it seems to work just like the circuit with 1 relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frmPvU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Furthermore, using \$Cmin>\frac{4*L}{Rcoil^2}\$ formula from TE’s [application note](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Catalog%20Section%7FAxicom_AppNote_5%7F0513%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CS_Axicom_AppNote_5_0513_AXICOM_AN5_LatchingRelays-r.pdf%7F1-1422002-0), the capacitor calculation for 1 relay is 148uF (Where R=90 ohms from datasheet for the relay and assuming .3H inductance). For 2 relays in parallel, I assumed the inductance and resistances can be calculated as if they are in parallel as well. Therefore, Rtotal = 45 ohms and Ltotal = .15H. With these numbers, the Cmin is 74uF. However, with my test and Falstad simulation result, I found I needed more capacitance not less. I feel like I’m really missing something when I’m paralleling the relays?

I also figured out later on that the standard BC547 is rated for 100ma. With each relay requiring 33ma to pick-up, I probably can’t test with more than 3 relays. Could the third relay be maxing out the transistor? I don’t have a scope to test current spike. (Will order a higher rated transistor in the meantime).

No freewheeling diode was added here as it would prevent this circuit from working as the required reverse current would simply bypass the coils through the diode. Does this mean the transistor will have a short life?

I have searched all over trying to solve this. I feel like I’m not accounting for something when paralleling the relays. I may be way off track or really close to the solution. The goal here is to reduce BOM count by paralleling the relays, using 1 or two large capacitors and one transistor switch for all 4 relays. Any help in shedding light on this as well as better alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: So I skipped the transistor switch part of the circuit and manually switched the circuit from +5 to GND per the TE app note. And each time, it worked perfectly for all 4 relays in parallel with just 100uF capacitor. This tells me, the fact that I have them in parallel may not be the issue. It may be the transistor not fully turning-on on power loss. Would a depletion mode P-Channel FET work better in this case?
[image]
[image: d]

Comment: Have you considered a "Step Relay" ?

Comment: You need to provide a 1 shot pulse to Set and Reset , When put in parallel L's are added and with C , the resonant frequency is increased. that may not allow the current to be what you expect if the Q is too high .  Why not use a 1 shot but how to close when power is lost?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that I'm using a polarized cap mean the current flow in one direction and therefore no resonance? (not sure). Also, at power on, the "pulse" occurs until the capacitor charges. once charged, no more current.

Comment: Looks like you have solved you own problem - why not use a SPDT switch and wire it like you did in the experiment?

Comment: Well... need it to switch automatically. Not manually. Either way.... I simulated a P-Chanel MOSFET circuit that switches ON when voltage is lost. Ordering parts now to test and will post. Thanks!